# Reset form values in JQuery Validator submitHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I Have a simple Jquery Validation that calls Ajax, but after call the Ajax page I want to reset the form. All works fine but its do not reseting the form.

My JQuery and Validate Script:

```
var validator = $('#formOne').validate({
    rules: {
        fieldName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(this).callAjax(form);
        validator.resetForm(); 
        return false; //avoid form submit
    }
});

//Ajax call function
$.fn.callAjax= function(form){
        var postData = $(form).serialize(); 
        var formAction = $(form).attr('action')     
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: formAction,
            data: postData,          
            dataType: "html",      
            success: function(response){                    
                $("#ShowNames").html(response); 
            }           
        });
 }
```

My Form:

```
<form name="formOne" id="formOne" method="post" action="ajax/insert_name.php?act=insert">
   <input type="text" id="fieldName" name="fieldName">
   <button type="submit" id="loading-btn" value="Submit" data-loading-text="Loading...">Avançar</button>
</form>
<div id="ShowNames"></div>
```

I've tried lots of ways but I couldn't make this work...

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
validator.resetForm();
```

Without $

[Documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.resetForm/)

Comment: Good call. Best to use a method that's actually `supposed to be used` with the plugin! :)

Comment: Tks Dox, was my mistake the $, but I've removed and it still not working... Any ideas??

Comment: Strange What about $(form).validate().resetForm(); ?

Comment: Annoying fact about jQuery Validate's `resetForm` it doesn't remove the values from the form, so you still have to call `form.reset()`.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT*

Taking into account you're using the jQuery Validation plugin, a `better and more concise` answer has been provided by [Dox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2397358/dox).

I'm not sure why you used `$validator.resetForm();` because I don't see `$validator` referencing anything. That being said, you should probably either clear your form *in* your AJAX success function, or check if some condition is true *after* your AJAX function runs.

The code you're looking for (if used in the AJAX success function) would look like:

```
//Ajax call function
$.fn.callAjax= function(form){
        var postData = $(form).serialize(); 
        var formAction = $(form).attr('action')     
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: formAction,
            data: postData,          
            dataType: "html",      
            success: function(response){                    
                $("#ShowNames").html(response); 
                // If some condition is true
                $(form)[0].reset();
            }           
        });
 }
```

Comment: Tks John, I can't call inside the callAjax function because there is another forms that use the same function and I don't need this form to be cleared... By the way your condition $(form)[0].reset(); works fine in submitHandler... But I wanna work with it validator.resetForm();... If I cant I will check your answer..